# Microsoft Excel: How to pick the correct cell based on a different column?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match, vlookup

**Update**:

I've managed to get Excel to pick a rate based on what date range it falls under.

I now need something (in combination with my new formula below)to only pick those rates according to the currency.
So If I have two exchange rates, EUR and GBP with the same date range of 01/05/18 to 20/05/18. And I made a payment in GBP, I need it to select the GBP rate.
As you can see below, my formula is picking 1.2, which is the EUR rate and not GBP.

Here is my updated formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$94:$B$95<=C99)/($C$94:$C$95>=C99),$G$94:$G$95)
```

I have simplified my screenshots I initial added for the convenience of the viewers:

[image]

**Initial Question**:

I'm dealing with accounting dates, where the new month may start on 26th for example.

Currently, I have formula set up to pick a exchange rate based on what **month** a payment was made.
So if I paid something on May, excel will get the exchange rate from May.

But I now need it to pick it based on a specific date. 
So if I made a payment on the 26th of May, but the account month start on the 20th of May, I need it to pick the June currency.

I'm not quite sure how to do this, maybe, two ifs statements <=01/05/18  and >=20/05/18.
Or perhaps, create a range of dates in once cell?

Current formula:

> =SUMIFS('Exchange Rates'!F9:F1378, **table of exchange rates**
>   'Exchange Rates'!B9:B1378,L563, **picks up what currency to use EUR or GBP**
>   'Exchange Rates'!D9:D1378,TEXT(J563,"yyyymm")) **picks up what date to use**

[image: Formula under Col U]

[image: Exchange rate list]

Comment: From the tables how do you know the account month started on the 20th? The `Book Period` column only has the year and month in it.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. So I have the date ranges, but I'm not sure how I should be inputting them in the Book Period. Currently, that's how the table sits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just combine all criteria in single `SUMIFS()` (quite similar to what you did initially) :

`=SUMIFS($D$1:$D$2;$A$1:$A$2;"<="&A4;$B$1:$B$2;">="&A4;$C$1:$C$2;B4)`

Based on the following reduced data-set (starting in cell A1, with the formula in D4) :

```
20-Sep-18   25-Oct-18   GBP     1.15
20-Sep-18   25-Oct-18   EUR     1.2


25-Sep-18               GBP     1.15
```

Comment: @Sat10  You're welcome. Please note that it's a very "bare" formula, without any error handling, so you have to be quite sure about the quality of your dataset. If the conditions are not met, the result will be 0, but if you would have two rows that match the criteria (e.g. because the 'Date From' and 'Date End' have some overlap) the result would be of course the sum of the two rates, which is rather a big mistake ;). You could mitigate this by using `AVERAGEIFS()`, or you can wrap everything with a `COUNTIFS()` to have more control over what should happen in such cases.